# Note: PHPUnit is required in order to generate controller test stubs

Tags: php, zend-framework

Here is my command on the terminal and I got a notice message

```
Note: PHPUnit is required in order to generate controller test stubs.

volition@volition-H61M-DS2:/var/www/register$ zf create action root Authentication

Note: PHPUnit is required in order to generate controller test stubs.

Creating an action named root inside controller at /var/www/register/application/controllers/AuthenticationController.php
Updating project profile '/var/www/register/.zfproject.xml'
Creating a view script for the root action method at /var/www/register/application/views/scripts/authentication/root.phtml
Updating project profile '/var/www/register/.zfproject.xml'
```

This is my include_path:

```
include_path    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

and also I want to know what is the use of phpUnit ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just is what it says. If you want to create test stubs, you need to have [PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de/) installed. Zend can automatically create tests for you when you generate code. It's not an error or a *notice* (as in `E_NOTICE`), it's simply a *Note*.

PHPUnit is a unit testing framework that helps you to test your code. If you don't know what that means, by all means go read the [PHPUnit documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/automating-tests.html).

Comment: :) what i need to add here include_path    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear

Comment: :)I am not sure i am not the owner of the system what i am using so how can i check this ?

Comment: For example: `$ php -r 'echo class_exists("PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase");'` or just `$ phpunit`.

Answer (score -2):

```
First, install PEAR.

sudo apt-get install php-pear
Next, tell PEAR to update its own channel.

sudo pear channel-update pear.php.net
Then, tell PEAR to upgrade itself to the newest version.

sudo pear upgrade-all
You should now have the newest version of PEAR installed.

To install PHPUnit, let PEAR know where to find PHPUnit.

sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
Then install PHPUnit. (the -a makes sure all dependency packages are also installed)

sudo pear install -a phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Update:

At Last Restart Apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

ohh You are using zend Framework

```
phpunit is installed in 
C:\Zend\ZendServer\bin\PEAR
```

Add this line

`include_path=".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php/PHPunit:/usr/share/php/PEAR"`

Comment: what i need to add here include_path    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear